# rowspan is removed when using dataview in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates, dataview

I have the below template

```
<ul class="sys-template" id="visitingCard">
  <li id="{{UiId}}">
    <div class="profiles">
      <div class="profile">
        <table border="1" style="width: 100%; ">
          <tr >
            <td rowspan="3" >
              Hello Dear
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              ABC : ABC
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              XXX : XXX
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In script, I am creating dataview as below:

```
var data=$create(
                   Sys.UI.DataView, 
                   {  data: 
                          { 
                             UiId: "UiId:1", 
                             UiName: "test"
                           } 
                   }, 
                   null, 
                   null, 
                   $get("visitingCard")
                 );
```

Rowspan specified in td is removed when I use `$create()` in IE. Can any one provide a solution for this?